# SQL Server Switch statement dependent on where foreign key is

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an existing database which has the following design:

[image]

What I want to be able to do is to update a column based on where the foreign key is set. An asset header is only ever related to one Asset Type (Truck/Trailer/Plant/Car)

Pseudo code example:

```
UPDATE assets.AssetHeader
SET FleetExportAssignmentMethod = 1, 
    DataCaptureUnit = CASE
                         WHEN TRUCK THEN RegistrationNumber
                         WHEN TRAILER THEN ChassisNumber
                         WHEN COMPANYCAR THEN RegistrationNumber
                         WHEN PLANT THEN RegistrationNumber
                      END
```

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: Looks like Asset GroupID is the column you would use, assuming that is the ID in your vehicle tables.  Looks like poor design, could have just had 1 table with all that info and an AssetType in your vehicle table instead of different tables for all of them

Comment: The tables actually have about 30-40 different columns that differ across asset types, hence splitting the tables. Asset Group != Asset Type

Comment: Ok, that makes sense then, but should have assettype in the asset table to tell you what table it will be going to

Comment: Fair Point, I will get that added in as well. Thanks

Comment: No problem, let you tell what table it goes to just by looking at it instead of hunting for what tables.  Then your code above can just use that field to identify which one it is and not needing to do the solution below (that would work but a lot more expensive of a query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to bring in the values and then `COALESCE()` to choose amongst them:

```
UPDATE ah
    SET FleetExportAssignmentMethod = 1, 
        DataCaptureUnit = COALESCE(t.RegistrationNumber, tr.ChassisNumber, cc.RegistrationNumber, p.RegistrationNumber)
    END
    FROM assets.AssetHeader ah LEFT JOIN
         TRUCK t
         ON t.AssetHeaderId = ah.id LEFT JOIN
         TRAILER tr
         ON tr.AssetHeaderId = ah.id LEFT JOIN
         COMPANYCAR cc
         ON cc.AssetHeaderId = ah.id LEFT JOIN
         PLANT p
         ON p.AssetHeaderId = ah.id;
```